# 3D visualization of cylindrical trajectory

Tags: c++, qt, 3d, visualization, qt3d

As Qt developers know, in new Qt version, Qt 3D has been extended a lot. `QtDataVisualization`, `Qt3DCore`, `Qt3DExtras` and so on are the new examples have recently been added in Qt.

Because there are only a few examples of 3D, I ask about that. I have in mind to draw a 3D visualization of cylindrical trajectory as shown in the picture. Is it possible in Qt? Is it worth to spend my time to learn that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Open Asset Import Library (Assimp)](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/main_features_formats.html) is a part of Qt3D, you can definitely import a variety of 3D formats.

If you want to create cylinders or something cylinder-like, then this example https://doc.qt.io/GammaRay/gammaray-qt3d-geometry-example.html is very enlightening.